# maximum likelihood and mse(mean square error)

Tags: maximum-likelihood, gaussian

[image]

thisis the equation of maxilum likelihood

[image]

Then this is maximum likelihgood when the distribution is Gaussian distribution.

I want to know to to derive the bottom equation from the left ?

Comment: Don't post unsearchable images.  Instead, typeset your full question (in *MathJax*).

Answer (score 0):

The PDF of the (univariate) [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is

$$\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{y - \hat{y}}{\sigma}\right)^2\right]$$

This is your $P_{model}(y_i\ | \
x_i ; \theta)$ for a single observation. Assuming each observation is independent, the likelihood (probability of observing $y_1...y_m$ together) is 
$$\prod_{i = 1}^m P_{model}(y_i\ | \
x_i ; \theta).$$ 
Taking the log of this whole expression gives your result.

Comment: can you show some detail?

Comment: Is something unclear? I'm not sure what you're confused about